# Select statement containing an alias

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been practicing some SQL recently and I have some code that, whilst is is functioning, I feel is has very bad syntax and isn't really the most efficient.

My goal is to give the dates when the film/s with the most inventory were rented. As you can see below, I join 2 selects, one which contains the frequency of the film in an inventory, and one which gets the date from the rental table with the rental id. I think for my current knowledge this is good so far, but but my current room for improvement is my WHERE statement "WHERE ciid IN" (SELECT......). I just modified the previous code to get the max value.

My question is, is there a way in which I can make the WHERE statement smaller/more efficient (instead of having to evaluate the statements again)

I was thinking it might be possible to do something like making the entire statement original statement aliased? or changing the select statement to something like

```
WHERE ciid IN (SELECT MAX(ciid) FROM amount LEFT JOIN someDate ON.....)
```

or even

```
WHERE ciid IN (SELECT MAX(ciid) FROM aliasedTable)
```

Are there any best practices that I should adhere to or any syntax that I am missing that would allow me to do these things?

I apologies preemptively for my messy code, I'm not the most experienced in SQL.

```
SELECT film.title, rdate FROM (
    (
        SELECT 
        film_id fid1, COUNT(*) ciid 
        FROM inventory 
        GROUP BY film_id
        ORDER BY ciid)amount
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT inventory.film_id fid2, rental_date rdate 
        FROM rental 
        LEFT JOIN inventory 
        ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id)someDate
    ON amount.fid1 = someDate.fid2)h 
    LEFT JOIN film ON film.film_id = fid1
    WHERE ciid IN (SELECT MAX(ciid) FROM (SELECT 
     film_id fid1, COUNT(inventory_id)ciid 
     FROM inventory 
     GROUP BY film_id
     ORDER BY ciid)amount
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT inventory.film_id fid2, rental_date rdate 
        FROM rental 
        LEFT JOIN inventory 
        ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id) 
                   someDate
                   ON amount.fid1 = someDate.fid2
                  );
```

rental:

- rental_id
- rental_date
- inventory_id
- customer_id
- return_date
- staff_id
- last_update

inventory:

- inventory_id
- film_id
- store_id
- last_update

film:
only necessary information here is

- film_id
- title

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

The expected output is something along the lines of

```
+--------+--------+
| title  | date   |
+--------+--------+
| title1 |   date |
| title1 |   date |
| title1 |   date |
| title2 |   date |
| title2 |   date |
| ...    |   ...  |
+--------+--------+
```

Doing some of the queries manually to check, I expect 2000 outputs.

Basically all the code is doing is getting all the items with the highest level of inventory, and then returning all the times that they were rented.

also here is the drive link with the ddl: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t4if95Jsfg9LqbNkTph1h5vFMnBz9SGY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results of that data, as formatted text - **no images**. Please see [why no Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).Additionally post the full table definition (ddl) also as text.  As alternative create and post a fiddle from [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) or [db<>fiddle uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: sure! really sorry about the hassle

Comment: No worry, it happens especially until you have several posts and get use to the process.

Comment: Hey @Belayer I've made most of the edits and I will just load up my ddl in a sec